# Best study tools on the net or books

Tags: theravada, sutras, study

I currently don't have a teacher and I'm looking for good study guides for the sutta's. I mean I'm reading them but when it comes to interpretation often I'm at a loss. Is there a source(s) or book(s) that can help with this? I know they're is no substitute for s teacher but until such time I'm working on my on.

Comment: See also [English (or other European) translations of Pali Canon](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/4109/254) and [Chronological or other sequence for beginners](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/4112/254)

Answer (score 2):

Piya Tan at http://dharmafarer.org has translations and commentary of many of the suttas. Using the "sitemap" on the right or bottom of the page, you can find specific suttas (sorted by number), or, his "sutta discovery (SD) series" which is sorted thematically.

Some people disagree with [some of] his commentary (see e.g. [this topic](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/14521/254)).

Answer (score 1):

This website is the best study tool because if you ask about a certain sutta I can explain it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanissaro Bhikkhu's "Wings to Awakening" (https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/thanissaro/wings/index.html) is a good interpretive guide to the suttas for practitioners. Also see the "Beginnings" material at this same site (https://www.accesstoinsight.org/).

Answer (score 0):

"[The Discourse on Right View: The Sammaditthi Sutta and its Commentary](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nanamoli/wheel377.html)" translated from the Pali by Bhikkhu Ñanamoli, and edited and revised by Bhikkhu Bodhi, may be of interest to you.

[Right View](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-ditthi/index.html) is said to be the forerunner of the [Noble Eightfold Path](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/bodhi/waytoend.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is a good website for early Buddhist texts : https://suttacentral.net/

Comment: It has translations of the suttas. Does it have "study guides" too?

Comment: You are right it does not , sorry about that!